# From TCP/IP network to IPX/SPX network?

Tags: networking, router, tcpip

Ok so can a computer from a TCP/IP network communicate with a computer from a IPX/SPX network? If so how will the routers handle the addressing scheme? And what if i wanna telnet that computer from the IPX/SPX network, should I use the IPX addressing scheme even if my network is using the IP addressing scheme. And anyone please give an example of a IPX address? Don't know what it looks like.

Comment: Why don't we throw ES-IS into the mix while we're at it?

Comment: How is IPX/SPX not dead yet?  **Please*** spend your time trying to ***get rid of this dinosaur of a protocol***, not trying to find ways to prop it up :-)

Answer (score 4):

The 1980's called and they want their networking back...

Ok all joking aside no you cannot directly communicate from an IPX/SPX host and an IP host without first going through either a proxy or a tunnel.  Much like how you cannot have an IPv4 host talk to an IPv6 host.  You can however have IPX and IP traffic coexist on the same network as they can both run on top of Ethernet.

As for IPX addresses they consist of 12 bytes, 4 network, 6 host, 2 socket.  The following is an example address:  01a83f03 c42c03087a07 10a9.  The host portion can be the MAC address of the host.  The network segment can also be written as 00000000 which would mean the current network the host is attached to.